# How to map object in indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

In my xml :
    
    sachin
    nitin
    ravi
    deepak
    
i have created "tag1" object style in indesign template. because i want to apply background style for "tag1", but this should not manually, because there is multiple occurrence. please suggest how to map object style to "tag1" automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

In your template open Structure panel, select from the top menu and "Map tags to styles". Here you can assign multiple tags to the same style and save it.

The other option is to add style link as an attribute to your xml. I know it works with paragraph style, not sure about the object styles: E.g.

```
<sachin aid:pstyle="tag1">
```

You will need to add an adobe namespace to your xml.